# Employee not found with id null grails

Tags: grails, groovy

Can someone help me with my situation. I have the following code.

```
class Employee {

    Integer empId
    String firstName
    String lastName

    static constraints = {
        empId()
        firstName()
        lastName()
    }

    static mapping = {
        id generator:'assigned', name:'empId'
        version false
    }
}
```

The code allows me to save employee through 'create' but gives the following error message

"Employee not found with id null" and also in the list, all the employees are listed but clicking on any Emp Id gives the same error. Please help. This is driving me nuts.

Rocky

---

Thanks for your reply. Like I mentioned I am able to save the empId in the database but get that message nonetheless and see the list with assigned ids (empId). The  link points to employee/show with no number at end. However employee/show/22(empId) works fine. employee/edit/22 works too but update does not work.

I am not using any assigned sequence. Just some random integer. Maybe a better example would be to use SSN instead of empId.

Thank you once again.

---

You are a great help buddy. Appreciate your time and patience. I am not writing any special update or save (I am too new to dig too deep). Just using grails to generate-all. However, I did find a workaround. I  changed the domain class to add variable id (Long) and added empId setter method to allocate the empId value to id. That did it. Here is my code.

class Employee {
    Long id
    Long empId
    String firstName
    String lastName

```
static constraints = {
    empId()
    firstName()
    lastName()
}

static mapping = {
    id generator:'assigned', name:'empId', column: 'emp_id'
    version false
}

public void setEmpId(Long empId){
    this.empId = empId
    this.id = empId
}
```

}

Please feel free to suggest if you have a better way of doing that.

Regards

Rocky

Comment: one more thing, I am running generate-all Employee, if that helps. Is it that generate-all does not work unless the primary key is id.

Comment: Ok. So you are assigning ids to your objects, right? Would you post your update and save actions so it's easier to figure out what's happening?

Comment: Hey Tiago, you are a great help buddy. I did not create any special save or update, just used grails to generate that all. However, I found a workaround. this is what I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the "assigned" sequence, then you have to assign the objects ids yourself before saving them. Otherwise your objects will be saved with a null or 'default 0' id. If you want GORM to assign an id for you, you need to use another type of generator, like "sequence" generator. It would be like:

```
id name: 'customId', generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence:'some_sequence']
```

More info on id generators [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html).